# Dotpeek or dnSpy filter for .NET Core Assemblage

Tags: .net-core, dotpeek, dnspy

I am working in the context of a .NET Core application, windows service, and I have a compiler error telling me I've got a type that has moved assemblies. I cannot find said type and I have gone all over looking for it. So far, I have tried using a combination of dnSpy, Dotpeek, and [try.dot.net](https://try.dot.net) to reference pertinent nuget packages or .dlls' local to my machine to find the System.Security type(s) I'm looking for. Error for the Type is as follows and afaik an assemblage with that version does not exist...anywhere!

> The type name 'DirectorySecurity' could not be found in the namespace
>   'System.Security.AccessControl'. This type has been forwarded to
>   assembly 'System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl, Version=4.0.4.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a
>   reference to that assembly.

Is there a way I can use external tooling to filter or find a type on my machine that the compiler is asking for? I have referenced all manner of dependencies (individually) in Visual Studio then subsequently removed them if that did not satisfy the compiler.

In any event, any help would be appreciated - thanks!

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl/

Comment: @HansPassant thanks, I am aware of what the shape of that package looks like i.e., I see that DirectorySecurity is in the namespace but for some reason Visual Studio doesn't agree with us even if we reference that package from NuGet or on my machine (partly because I can't find the System.Security.AccessControl dll on my machine with the DirectorySecurity Type). ALSO, that package does not have a 4.0.4.0 version.

Comment: The semantic version number (like 4.3.0) has lost all relevance to the [AssemblyVersion] number (like 4.0.4.0).  Big problem.  We don't know anything about the kind of .NETCore or .NETStandard project you created and what version you target, makes it awfully hard to help you.

Comment: Upon further inspection of the current version (4.7) of the nuget-package that specific implementation is .NET Standard compliant with NET Core 2.0 and not 3.0 yet...so I have to downgrade the project, find a different workaround, or wait until the System.Security.AccessControl library is compliant with 3.0+.

Answer (score 0):

Upon further inspection of the the nuget-package the version of the specific library (and subsequent type) is .NET Standard compliant only with NET Core 2.0 and under; not 3.0 yet...so I have to downgrade the project, find a different workaround, or wait until the System.Security.AccessControl library is compliant with 3.0+.